# Image uploading to DB using jQuery and ASMX web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

How to upload image using jQuery (AJAX) and ASMX web service - asp.net?

I searched google for a simple script but nothing...

I only need server side code (Web Method) that can recive file form jquery json post using html  or asp.net file upload conrol if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make ajax file uploads. There are several sites that make tricks with iframes or flash (like gmail does) to do this task. For example:

1. http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html
2. http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

These examples are for php, but should also work for asp.net changing the server side logic.